# Highlight text in sms android with regex

Tags: android, regex

I want a regular expression to highlight text (underline) in sms like default sms app in android phone.
 
I have tested for some matched cases:

```
   Number: 06464, +86786, +84 879, ff765756765thw        /*more than 5 digits */
   Web address: abc.com, http://google.com
   Email address: abc@gmail.com
   Date:   2012.12.02
```

[image: highlight text]

I tried searching in android OS source code but it didn't help. How can I get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank to Sana, based on your hint, I found all things in [Pattern.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/util/Patterns.java)
For example:
- Phone:

```
public static final String PHONE =
// sdd = space, dot, or dash
"(\\+[0-9]+[\\- \\.]*)?" // +<digits><sdd>*
        + "(\\([0-9]+\\)[\\- \\.]*)?" // (<digits>)<sdd>*
        + "([0-9][0-9\\- \\.][0-9\\- \\.]+[0-9])"; // <digit><digit|sdd>+<digit>
```

-Email:

```
public static final String EMAIL_ADDRESS = "[a-zA-Z0-9\\+\\.\\_\\%\\-\\+]{1,256}"
        + "\\@"
        + "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\\-]{0,64}"
        + "("
        + "\\."
        + "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\\-]{0,25}" + ")+";
```

Answer (score 3):

have you used `android:autoLink="web|phone|email"` in the `TextView` which is displaying your numbers or web address or email? But for the date you might want to implement a regex!

Comment: The problem is I want to get regex because my app use canvas act like the TextView

Comment: What is the layout which you will use?

Comment: Linear layout. But I want to get regex, NOT an android config. I found this from your advice: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4363041/719212. That is the thing I want. Can you give me the other?